# CKFinder Plugin - PHP - Remove Space if Found when Renaming a Folder

Tags: php, plugins, ckeditor, directory, ckfinder

I need the communities help, I need to create a plugin that checks users input when Renaming a Folder. The plugin should check the new Renamed folder and before saving should remove any space that is found.

I am stuck in the removeFolderSpace function and I am not sure how to complete it. If anyone is willing to help I appreciate greatly!

```
<?php
namespace CKSource\CKFinder\Plugin\FolderSpace;

use CKSource\CKFinder\Acl\Permission;
use CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Config;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Command\CommandAbstract;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Event\CKFinderEvent;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Event\RenameFolderEvent;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Filesystem\Folder\Folder;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Filesystem\Folder\WorkingFolder;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Plugin\PluginInterface;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Filesystem\Path;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class FolderSpace implements PluginInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $app;

    public function setContainer(CKFinder $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    protected $requires = [
        Permission::FOLDER_RENAME,
    ];

    public function getDefaultConfig() {
        return [];
    }

    public function removeFolderSpace(RenameFolderEvent $event) {
        $config = $this->app['config'];
        //$dispatcher = $this->app['dispatcher'];

        // $dispatcher->addListener(CKFinderEvent::AFTER_COMMAND_RENAME_FILE, function(AfterCommandEvent $e) {

        // });

        $request = $event->getRequest();


        $workingFolder = $this->app['working_folder'];



    }


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [CKFinderEvent::AFTER_COMMAND_RENAME_FILE => 'removeFolderSpace'];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this result you will need to create a small plugin for both: frontend (JavaScript) and connector (PHP).

PHP plugin bootstrap code:

```
namespace CKSource\CKFinder\Plugin\SanitizeFolderName;

use CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Event\CKFinderEvent;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Event\RenameFolderEvent;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Plugin\PluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class SanitizeFolderName implements PluginInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $app;

    public function setContainer(CKFinder $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function getDefaultConfig()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function onFolderRename(RenameFolderEvent $event)
    {
        $event->setNewFolderName(str_replace(' ', '_', $event->getNewFolderName()));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            CKFinderEvent::RENAME_FOLDER => 'onFolderRename'
        ];
    }
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
CKFinder.start({
    onInit: function(finder) {
        finder.on('command:before:RenameFolder', function() {
            finder.once('command:before:GetFiles', function(evt) {
                var folder = evt.data.folder;
                folder.set('name', folder.get('name').replace(/ /g, '_'));
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code worked for CreateFolder command but when I try RenameFolder whenever I rename a folder it displays an error and screen blanks out and keeps giving me an error whenever i open ckfinder on the front end but folder does get renamed on the file structure. On the log it displays a WorkingFolder as not found.